# Negating a complex regex containing three parts

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need a regex which is matched when the string doesn't have both lowercase and uppercase letters.

- If the string has only lowercase letters -> should be matched
- If the string has only uppercase letters -> should be matched
- If the string has only digits or special characters -> should be matched

For example

`abc`, `ABC`, `123`, `abc123`, `ABC123&^` - should match

`AbC`, `A12b`, `AB^%12c` - should not match

Basically I need an inverse/negation of the following regex:

> `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).+$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does not sound like any lookarounds would be needed.

Either match only characters that are [not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `a-z` or only characters, that are not `A-Z`.

```
^(?:[^a-z]+|[^A-Z]+)$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qbF0sI/1) (used [`+` for one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html))

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
^(?!.*[A-Z].*[a-z])(?!.*[a-z].*[A-Z])\S+$
```

Or

```
^(?=(?:[^a-z]+|[^A-Z]+)$).*$
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/yxePoP/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/oDA3Mc/1)

A lookaround solution like this can be used in more complex scenarios, when you need to apply more restrictions on the pattern. Else, consider a [non-lookaround solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59427845/3832970).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*[A-Z].*[a-z])` - no uppercase followed with a lowercase letter
- `(?!.*[a-z].*[A-Z])` - no lowercase letter followed with an uppercase one
- `(?=(?:[^a-z]+|[^A-Z]+)$)` - a positive lookahead that requires 1 or more characters other than lowercase ASCII letters (`[^a-z]+`) to the end of the string, or  1 or more characters other than uppercase ASCII letters (`[^A-Z]+`) to the end of the string
- `.+` - 1+ chars other than line break chars
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
^(([A-Z0-9?&%^](?![a-z]))+|([a-z0-9?&%^](?![A-Z]))+)$
```

You can test more cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/O8Vy78/2).

I've only added the characcter `?&%^` as possible character, but you could add which ever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
^(?:[^a-z]+?|[^A-Z]+?)$
```

It translates to "If the entire string is composed of non-lowercase letters or non-uppercase letters then match the string."

Lazy quantifiers `+?` are used so that the end-string `$` anchor is obeyed when the multiline flag is enabled. If you're only validating a single-line string the you can simply use `+` without the question mark.

If you have a whitelist of specific allowed special chars then change `[^A-Z]` into `[A-Z0-9()_+=-]` and list the allowed special chars.

https://regex101.com/r/Wg6tLn/1